# Can I fully complete (100%) Gears of War 3 without the Beta medal?

Tags: xbox-360, achievements, gears-of-war-3

There is a medal which is locked for me as I did not take part in the beta tests.

> "Beta Tester - Participated in the Beta"

Does this mean that I cannot complete the game to 100%?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose it depends on what you consider to be "100%" in the game.

Getting all of the achievements is what is required for the Xbox Dashboard to put a game in your "completed" list.  If you're going by [achievements](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/gears-of-war-3/guide/), there is no achievement that requires you to get every medal (Seriously 3.0 specifically does not include this medal), and no specific achievement for this medal.

Comment: Seriously 3.0 Requires lvl 100 and every Onyx medal... exept Beta tester.

Comment: Clarified, thanks for pointing out that that was confusing.